# Knocout js computed observable not updated

Tags: knockout.js

I am using numeral.js to format the numbers while displaying in my application. But when I apply the formatting and try to change my computed observable the value is not getting updated if the entered value is same as the formatted value.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kwt8vy9u/5/

```
   var ChangeWrite = true;
//Function to get first 2 non zero digits after decimal

ko.bindingHandlers.number = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data) {
        var observable = valueAccessor(),
            formatted = ko.computed({
                read: function (key) {
                    ChangeWrite = false;
                    if (ko.isObservable(observable)) {
                        if (observable() || observable() === 0) {
                            var num = parseFloat(observable());
                            return numeral(num).format('0,0.00');
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (observable || observable === 0) {
                            var num = parseFloat(observable)
                            return numeral(num).format('0,0.00');
                        }
                        return '';
                    }
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    if (ChangeWrite) {
                        var change = true;
                        if (value != valueAccessor()()) {
                            change = true;
                        } else {
                            change = false;
                        }
                        if (!isNaN(value) && value !== '' && change && value.indexOf('-') < 0) {
                            valueAccessor()(value);
                        } else {
                            if ((change || value.indexOf('-') >= 0) && $("#dgConfirm").is(':visible') == false) {
                                alert('please enter valid value');
                            }
                            $(element).val(function () {
                                if (valueAccessor()() === '') return '';
                                else {
                                    var num = valueAccessor()()
                                        return numeral(num).format('0,0.00');
                                }
                            }());
                        }
                    } else {
                        ChangeWrite = false;
                        $(element).val(function () {
                            if (valueAccessor()() === '') return '';
                            else {
                                var num = valueAccessor()()
                                return numeral(num).format('0,0.00');
                            }
                        }());

                    }

                },
                disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
            }).extend({
                notify: 'always'
            });
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, {
            value: formatted
        });
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#txtOriginal").blur(function () {
        ChangeWrite = true;
    });

    function AppViewModel() {
        this.value = ko.observable(10);
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
    ChangeWrite = true;
});
```

Ex: When I enter 10.562 in the text box it is formatted as 10.56 and the underlying computed observable contains 10.562 only. But when I change the value to 10.56 then the underlying computed observable is not updated. It is still using 10.562. This problem is seen in IE10 and chrome. It is working correctly in IE<=9

Thanks,

Praveen.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Can you simplify your example to focus on just the Knockout problem?

Comment: I have removed the unnecessary code and updated my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I opened your fiddle and replaced all the code with this:

```
$('#txtOriginal').change(function () {
    alert('Changed.');
});
```

And typed "1234" into your text box; and got the 'Changed.' alert.

I then deleted all the text, and typed "1234" again, and did NOT get the alert.

Based on this, I'm going to say that knockout is not getting your changed event, meaning the observable never even gets to see a change.